# How to kill a java process (by name) in Windows' cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, kill

When I run `jps -lv`, I get

> 4748 org.apache.abc.runtime.common.abc -XX:PermSize=128m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx512m -ea -Dproc_abc 11140 sun.tools.jps.Jps -Dapplication.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 -Xms8m

I need windows batch command to kill abc.

In linux,

```
taskkill /f /pid $(jps -lv   | grep abc   | awk '{print $1}')
```

this would be work but in windows, I can't not find how to do it.

Please help me.

Comment: I need windows command that works same as
taskkill /f /pid $(jps -lv | grep abc | awk '{print $1}')

Answer (score 3):

You can try it in batch like this :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('jps -lv ^| find /i "common"') do set PID=%%a
taskkill /f /PID %PID%
pause
```

Or like this way :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1" %%A in ('jps -lv ^| find "common"') do (taskkill /F /PID %%A)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`pskill`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896683) from SysInternals.

```
Usage: pskill [-t] [\\computer [-u username [-p password]]] 
     -t    Kill the process and its descendants.
     -u    Specifies optional user name for login to
           remote computer.
     -p    Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this
           you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
```

But for as more contemporary approach in Windows you would be better off with PowerShell and WMI.

Eg. To kill a FireFox process with "default" on the command line I could use:

```
(gwmi win32_process -filter 'name = "firefox.exe" and commandline like "%default%"').Handle | % { stop-process $_ }
```

`gwmi` is short for [`Get-WmiObject`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849824.aspx), the [`Win32_Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object uses its `Handle` property to hold the process id. `%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object` and executes the passed script block. `$_` is the current object being passed down the pipe,

Comment: I can not find pskill in my windows machine.
'pskill' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @이동준 You'll need to add pskill yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What I want to do is add a post-build step in jenkins, so I can not add it. I just can use windows batch command.

Comment: @이동준 There is now a fuller answer – I needed to remember the better way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! :)